# Register file extension as intent-filter to my application

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I have a problem with registering my file extension (e.g. .abc) to open my application.

Currently my manifest contains:

```
<activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        [...] >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With this code I'm able to open a .abc file from "ES File Explorer" with my application, but when I use the standard file browser from my device (LG G3) or use a file shortcut from my home screen, Android tries to open the .abc file with a pdf viewer from Google Docs.

I've also tried different variations with the categories BROWSABLE, ALTERNATIVE and SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE.

Why does Android perform different intents and how can I achieve to open .abc files always with my application?

I hope you can help me,
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

"Android tries to open the .abc file with a pdf viewer from Google Docs." is not very clear.I guess you mean that it actually does open it with pdf viewer without asking you which app you want to use to view the file.

If you have selected (as a user) to always handle .abc files with pdf viewer then that's the app that will handle .abc files. You have to clear that preference from your device's settings.

Comment: It tries to open the file but fails because its no pdf file. It seemes that this preference was set, so I resettet the Google Docs app. It still tries to open the .abc with the pdf viewer.

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I rename the file to .bcd (tried different extensions) Android still tries to open it with the pdf viewer. The message from ActivityManager in LogCat is `START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/APPLICATIONDIR/FILENAME.bcd flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity bnds=[0,850][288,1220]} from uid 10029 on display 0`

Comment: try making an intent using Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title); startActivity(chooser); This shows a list of apps that can handle the particular intent. So if your app is showing on that list then you know that you got it working right